# How to know UITableViewCell high?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have UITabelViewController with custom MyUITableViewCell.
MyUITableViewCell class has @IBOutlet MyTextView:UITextView and method:

```
func getHeight() -> CGFloat
    {
        let height = (self.MyTextView?.contentSize)!.height
        return height
    }
```

I need set high for cell depend textView content size.
In UITabelViewController I set high for TableViewCell:

```
   override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        let cell = tableView(_tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        println(cell.getHeight())
        return cell.getHeight()
    }
```

But println show 20.0 for all cells on output, although I see that real cell high in table is different.

Comment: If you are using auto layout, this is all done automatically for you provided the constraints are setup correctly. Check out a `What's new in UITableView and UICollectionView` videos from WWDC2014.

Comment: @Rog If delete estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath all cell size will the same and I see only part of text in TextView

Comment: Its because your estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath is called before your cellForRowAtIndexPath and current your cell is not created so it will take defaulr height as 20.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, refer to the video I posted in my previous comment. All your answers are there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the `UITableView`'s `rowHeight` method, like this:

```
tableView.rowHeight
```

Comment: It return -1.0. Cells has different hight.

Answer (score 0):

implement heightForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath